# I can't seem to pass the token from the auth.dart file to my Provider class

Tags: flutter

This is my main.dart file:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          ChangeNotifierProvider(
            create: (ctx) => Auth(),
          ),
          ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, Transactions>(
            update: (ctx, auth, previousTransactions) => Transactions(
                auth.token,
                previousTransactions == null
                    ? []
                    : previousTransactions.userTransactions),
          ),
        ],
```

This is my Auth.dart file:

```
class Auth with ChangeNotifier {
  String _token;
  DateTime _expiryDate;
  String _userId;

  bool get isAuth {
    return token != null;
  }

  String get token {
    if (_expiryDate != null &&
        _expiryDate.isAfter(DateTime.now()) &&
        _token != null) {
      return _token;
    }
    return null;
  }

  Future<void> signUp(String username, String password) async {
    const url =
        'https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key=APIKEY';
    try {
      final response = await http.post(
        url,
        body: json.encode(
          {
            'email': username,
            'password': password,
            'returnSecureToken': true,
          },
        ),
      );
      final responseData = jsonDecode(response.body);
      if (responseData['error'] != null) {
        throw HttpException(responseData['error']['message']);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }

  Future<void> logIn(String username, String password) async {
    const url =
        'https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=APIKEY';
    try {
      final response = await http.post(
        url,
        body: json.encode(
          {
            'email': username,
            'password': password,
            'returnSecureToken': true,
          },
        ),
      );
      final responseData = jsonDecode(response.body);
      if (responseData['error'] != null) {
        throw HttpException(responseData['error']['message']);
      }
       _token = responseData['idToken'];
      _userId = responseData['localId'];
      _expiryDate = DateTime.now().add(
        Duration(
          seconds: int.parse(responseData['expiresIn']),
        ),
      );
      notifyListeners();
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }
}
```

This is my Provider class which accepts the token:

```
class Transactions with ChangeNotifier {
  List<Transaction> _userTransactions = [
  ];

  final String authToken;

  Transactions(this.authToken, this._userTransactions);
```

The ProxyProvider code is prompting me to use create but I am already using update which passes the token and when I use create I get an error for not passing the token. How can I use both create and update in the Proxy Provider in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

You need define an update method on transactions provider like this

```
class Transactions with ChangeNotifier {
List<Transaction> _userTransactions = [
];

String? authToken;

void update(Auth auth) {
     final String newAuthToken = auth.token;
     authToken = newAuthToken;
}
```

Also you need a notifyListeners() to your token method on auth to trigger the update method.
This way you do not lose your state at Transactions so you do not neet to pass the previous transactions.

On your main.dart instead of rebuilding the whole provider (and losing state) you should call the update method like this

```
...
ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, Transactions>(
    update: (ctx, auth, Transactions) => Transactions!..update(auth),
),
...
```

This way the update method will update your authToken everytime you call the token method on your authProvider.
ChangeNotifierProxyProvider calls the update method everytime Auth Provider
notifies its listeners.